# Refreezing Fish? Safe?

Tags: food-safety, fish

So I bought some Atlantic salmon 2 days ago and put it in the freezer soon as we got it from the grocery.

Anyways last night I put it in the fridge to thaw out for today, well today's plan's got moved around and I didn't have a chance to cook it.....so I put it back in the freezer.

Is this safe? (if I decide to dethaw it again for the fridge)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as food *safety* goes, you are fine:
Neither was the fish in the [danger zone](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat) for the thawing, nor did you store it in the fridge for too long, even considering the second thaw in the future.

However, the food *quality* suffers from each freeze/thaw cycle:
Ice crystals damage cell walls and causes loss of liquid, which you then find in the freezer bag or in the pan instead of in your meat, meaning your fish can end up drier than unfrozen or after one cycle. Proper freezing technique minimizes that effect.
Note that sloppy cooking technique can be far worse with regard to dry fish... so unless you do repeated freeze/thaw cycles, you will probaby still very much enjoy your fish.